# Concat the table records based on the condtion

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssms

I am building a SSRS Report to show Student Class Information.
I have a table named class with information regarding classes students were attended. 
[image]

My requirement is to show the days in which the classes occur. For eg: If Column Name Monday = 'Y' then I have to show the day as [Mon].  I have tried below code .

```
SELECT 
    case when Monday   ='Y' then'[Mon]' else '' end +case when Monday ='Y' then ',' else '' end + 
    case when Tuesday  ='Y' then'[Tue]' else '' end +case when Tuesday ='Y' then ','else '' end + 
    case when Wednesday='Y' then'[Wed]' else '' end +case when Wednesday ='Y' then ',' else '' end + 
    case when Thursday ='Y' then'[Thu]' else '' end +case when Thursday ='Y' then ',' else '' end + 
    case when Friday   ='Y' then'[Fri]' else '' end +case when Friday ='Y' then ',' else ''  end + 
    case when Saturday ='Y' then'[Sat]' else '' end +case when Saturday ='Y' then ',' else ''  end + 
    case when Sunday   ='Y' then'[Sun]' else '' end as classday
    FROM vw_Class_Without_Instructor
```

I got the output as below.

[image]

In output there is an extra comma at the end of each line. Any way to exclude it in the select statement itself?. Is there any other way to get the output?. Use of case statements seems to be slow down the execution.

Comment: Hi you need a query for replacing comma or a separate query to get above output or both??

Comment: @Tarun I need both. I also concerned about any performance hits because of excessive use of case

Comment: @bmsqldev Please check my answer. It should work. I've improved query performance by reducing number of cases. Frankly you could have also used `PIVOT`. Also solution using `INNER QUERY` are a little expensive compared to striaght `select`

Comment: How can I use pivot for that. I think pivot is used to convert columns to rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this below query

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(case when Monday   ='Y' then',[Mon]' else '' end + 
    case when Tuesday  ='Y' then',[Tue]' else '' end +
    case when Wednesday='Y' then',[Wed]' else '' end +
    case when Thursday ='Y' then',[Thu]' else '' end +
    case when Friday   ='Y' then',[Fri]' else '' end +
    case when Saturday ='Y' then',[Sat]' else '' end +
    case when Sunday   ='Y' then',[Sun]' else '' end, 2,200) as classday
    FROM vw_Class_Without_Instructor
```

**trick:**  I've added commas with text so no half number of case evaluations. With `,[Mon]` value I've ensured that there is always a comma in beginning which is removed using `SUBSTRING`.
be wise to choose a very high value in last part parameter of SUBSTRING so that it return everything starting from the charindex in second part.

See msdn reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx

> If the sum of start and length is greater than the number of
>   characters in expression, the whole value expression beginning at
>   start is returned.

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution. but why u mentioned 200 as a delimiter for substring?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this;

```
select 
    CASE WHEN LEN(classday_with_comma) > 0 THEN LEFT(classday_with_comma,LEN(classday_with_comma) - 1) ELSE '' END as classday
From (
    SELECT 
        case when Monday    = 'Y' then '[Mon],' else '' end +
        case when Tuesday   = 'Y' then '[Tue],' else '' end +
        case when Wednesday = 'Y' then '[Wed],' else '' end +
        case when Thursday  = 'Y' then '[Thu],' else '' end +
        case when Friday    = 'Y' then '[Fri],' else '' end +
        case when Saturday  = 'Y' then '[Sat],' else '' end +
        case when Sunday    = 'Y' then '[Sun],' else '' end as classday_with_comma
    FROM vw_Class_Without_Instructor
)  as x
```

Two case statement can be truncated to one from

```
case when Monday   ='Y' then'[Mon]' else '' end + 
case when Monday ='Y' then ',' else '' end +
```

To

```
case when Monday    = 'Y' then '[Mon],' else '' end +
```

And

```
LEFT(classday_with_comma, LEN(classday_with_comma) - 1)
```

will remove the last `,`